# wp_get_object_terms() to get a list of all the terms attached to all the posts in the current query

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, terms

How can I use wp_get_object_terms() to get a list of all the terms attached to all posts in the current query?

For example, for the current query I want to get an array of the terms from the "Alfa" taxonomy that are contained in all the queried posts.

```
wp_get_object_terms($wp_query, 'alfa');
```

But that only seems to be returning one item in the array...

I am doing this to build an array to cross check one taxonomy with another for a navigation menu, and am currently doing this with the following code but I think there must be a better way.

Please help! Thanks!

```
$queried_terms = array();
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    $postid = $post->ID; 

    if( has_term( '', 'alfa', $postid) ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $postid, 'alfa' );
        foreach($terms as $term) {
            $queried_terms[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }

endwhile; endif;
rewind_posts();
wp_reset_query();

$queried_terms = array_unique($queried_terms);
```

Comment: Are you passing the whole `$wp_query` object to the function? I guess that is not correct.

Comment: I guess I'm just looking to see if the code I posted is the fastest way to get all posts from the query

Comment: Anything faster would take bunch of custom SQL... Are you interested in that or your current way will do?

Comment: I have a need for speed! If you know how to make that happen with a custom SQL, I would be forever grateful.

Comment: I think this and some modifications could make the trick http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50176/7314

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're on the right track because `wp_get_object_terms()` can take an array of IDs for its first argument, it's just that $wp_query is not the array you want.

I can't guarantee that this is more efficient (not my area of expertise), but I believe this [partially-tested] snippet would do what you want with at least one fewer loop and no `array_unique()`:

```
// get $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// get array of post objects    
$my_posts = $wp_query -> posts;
// make array for the post IDs
$my_post_ids = array();
// loop through posts array for IDs
foreach( $my_posts as $my_post ) {
    $my_post_ids[] = $my_post->ID;
}
// get the terms
$my_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $my_post_ids, 'alfa' );
```

`wp_get_object_terms()` takes a 3rd `$args` parameter which you may need to set to get the ouput you want, but I'll leave that to you.

UPDATE:
This can be even shorter using the new-to-me function [`wp_list_pluck()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck). Again this is untested but looks right:

```
// get $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// get array of post objects    
$my_posts = $wp_query -> posts;
// NEW: make array of the post IDs in one step
$my_post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $my_posts, 'ID' );
// get the terms
$my_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $my_post_ids, 'alfa' );
```

You can see [in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/functions.php#L3277) that this runs the same `foreach` loops code, but it looks a little nicer.

Comment: @j-man86 if this solved your problem, make sure to accept it as the answer. Otherwise, update your question and explain why this didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This generalisation of above worked for me:

```
$args = array( 'cat' = -1 ); // e.g. to get list of posts in any category
$postobjs = get_posts( $args );
$postids = wp_list_pluck( $postobjs, 'ID' );
$taxonomy = 'mytax' // your taxonomy name
$termobjs = wp_get_object_terms( $postids, $taxonomy );
$termlist = array_unique( wp_list_pluck( $termobjs, 'name' ) ); // distinct term names
```

It outputs a unique list of terms in the 'mytax' custom taxonomy. Thanks @mrwweb :-)

Comment: any idea why this wouldn't wouldn't work for woocommerce and pa_color?